# how to get the form name of current input text onchange in angular 2

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms

I have scenario where I am changing the input text, i have multiple forms and one input within each form so i want to get the current form name whose input i am changing. how to do this in angular 2??

Below is my code for child component

```
<form #form1="NgForm" novalidate>
  <input id="phoneNumber" type="text" placeholder="phoneNumber" class="validate"/>
</form>

<form #form2="NgForm" novalidate>
  <input id="mobileNumber" type="text" placeholder="mobileNumber" class="validate"/>
</form>
```

Now suppose i am adding mobile number i want its form name. How to do this angular 2?? This is i want to access in parent component I am accessing the child component form using @ViewChildren and i am able to access the form manually but i want access dynamically with respect to the input i am accessing ..

Answer (score 1):

In Angular you have two choices use dynamic forms or template driven forms,
your choice is dynamic forms using #form1="NgForm"

[Angular dynamic-form](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form)

In your code you forgot the '[formControlName]' directive on the inputs, when you have those you can access the form from your component code like:

**Component**:

```
this.form1.valueChanges.subscribe(data => console.log('Form changes', data));
```

**HTML**:

```
<form #form2="NgForm" novalidate>
  <input [formControlName]="mobileNumber" type="text" placeholder="mobileNumber" class="validate"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the current form valid invalid in parent form by passing index as input to child form and emitting the same in parent form...